# Next.js : URL with domain.com/category/post

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I have trouble understanding the dynamic URL routing to match my use case, and the examples only showcase structure like : domain.com/categories/category1, domain.com/posts/post-1.
As the title says, I would like to have the following URL structures on my blog, with Next.js :

- https://www.example.com/category1/post-1
- https://www.example.com/category1/post-2
- https://www.example.com/category1/post-3
- https://www.example.com/category2/post-4
- https://www.example.com/category2/post-5

...

I would also like the pages :

- https://www.example.com/category1
- https://www.example.com/category2

to be accessible.

So far, my file structure looks like this : [image] but I'm getting 404 errors.

Thank you for your help

Comment: _"I'm getting 404 errors"_ - What pages are 404ing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If that can be useful to someone else, I've found the solution.

The folder structure has to be like this :

```
pages
  [category]
    [slug.tsx] // (post page) 
    index.tsx // (category page)
```

In the [slug.tsx] page, your static paths must reflect the structure :

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const allPosts = await getAllPostsWithSlug();
  return {
    paths: allPosts?.map((post) => `/${post.category.slug}/${post.slug}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  };
};
```

In the index.tsx (category) page, likewise :

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const allCategories = await getAllCategories();
  return {
    paths: allCategories.map((category) => `/${category.slug}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  };
};
```

With this, I can access my posts with their category in the url.